# How to find object in recursion entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, recursion

I have the following case.

An object A has an object B that is recursive and I want to find object A if it contains any of the objects B

```
public class ObjectA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable 
    = false, length = 8)
    private TypeEnum type;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable 
    = false, length = 20)
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private ObjectB node;

     //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}

public class ObjectB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable 
    = false, length = 8)
    private TypeBEnum type;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable 
    = false, length = 20)
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private ObjectB parent;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }, mappedBy = "parent")
    private ObjectB children;

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

so i have this object:

```
ObjectA: {
    type: 'MyType',
    code: 'XXX',
    node: {
       type : 'FIRST',
       code : 'First Node',
       children : {
           type : 'SECOND',
           code : 'Second Node',
           children : {
               type : 'THIRD',
               code : 'Third Node'
           } 
       }
   }
}
```

My Repository:

```
public interface ObjectADao
        extends JpaRepository<ObjectA, Long>, 
JpaSpecificationExecutor<ObjectA> {
@Query("SELECT c FROM ObjectA c "
        + "INNER JOIN ObjectB n "
        + "ON c.node.id = n.id "
        + "WHERE c.type = :type AND c.code = :code "
        + "AND c.node = :node")
    Optional<ChainEntity> findBy(@Param("type") TypeEnum type, 
@Param("code") String code, @Param("node") ObjectBEntity node);
```

}

In this case I can get my ObjectA if I pass the full ObjectB.

What I need is that it be more flexible and given the type and code of the object A and one or two nodes obtain all the object

For example, objectA has the requested type and code and has a node that is of the 'THIRD' as type and 'Third Node' as code.

OR 
objectA has the requested type and code and has a node that is of the 'THIRD' as type and 'Third Node' as code and  has a node that is of the 'SECOND' as type and 'Second Node' as code.

Thx

Comment: `ObjectBEntity` is not `ObjectB`, where is the recursion?

Comment: it was a mistake thank you for the remark

Comment: Have you tried just removing the node parameter from method and query? If the relationship is OneToOne and the type+code is unique it should be possible to query the object that way.

Comment: Some dbms provide syntax for recursive queries, you could write a native query then

Comment: Im using mariaDB and i didnt fint a solution. @Nestor Sokil how you do that i didnt stand

Comment: @Matheus please provide an example of what you expect to get from the query, because nobody wants to answer when they don't understand the question.

Comment: I need to obtain the object A filtered by its type and code and that contains the node or nodes that you want as filters. For example I want the ObjectA with the type 'MyType' and the code 'XXX' that contains the objectB with the type : 'THIRD' and the code : 'Third Node'

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then this is a way to do it.

I replaced `children` field with `child`, which is more correct since the relationship is OneToOne.

Anyway this is an SQL query that would allow you to do something like that (shouldn't be too hard to convert it to JPA):

```
SELECT parent.*, child1.*, child2.* 
FROM ObjectA parent
INNER JOIN ObjectB child1
ON parent.node_id = child1.id
INNER JOIN ObjectB child2
ON child1.child_id = child2.id
WHERE parent.code = "XXX"
AND parent.type = "MyType"
AND child1.code = "Third Node"
AND child1.type = "THIRD"
AND child2.code = "Second Node"
AND child2.type = "SECOND";
```

However, with this you won't be able to query hierarchies with arbitrary depth, you will have to define a query for each depth if you need to. To achieve maximum flexibility and performance with such data structures you should consider using a graph database like [Neo4J](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j) or [OrientDb](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb).

UPDATE:

I was sure that MySQL doesn't support this, so I kind of derived from it that MariaDB doesn't either. However, it seems like Maria 10.2.2+ does support a `WITH RECURSIVE` and you said you couldn't find it. So are you on an older version then?
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/

Comment: Thx, The solution I was looking for is not to declare each level but something more generic

Answer (score 0):

I apply the solution of WITH RECURSIVE with which I do not feel comfortable but I do not find a more neat way of doing it.

I had to make the code native sql because JPA does not recognize or I did not find the way to do it and this depends on the version of the database so if it changes I have to validate the continuity of the function.

> I have made the relationship bidirectional bethween objectA <->
>   objectB

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM object_a AS a WHERE id IN ("
    + " WITH RECURSIVE parents AS ("
    + " SELECT id, code, parent_id, object_a_id"
    + " FROM object_b"
    + " WHERE type = :type AND code = :code"
    + " UNION ALL"
    + " SELECT b.id, b.code, b.parent_id, b.object_a_id"
    + " FROM object_b b, parents p"
    + " WHERE b.id = p.parent_id )"
    + " SELECT object_a_id FROM parents WHERE object_a_id is not null)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ObjectA> findByTypeAndNode(@Param("type") String type, @Param("code") String code);
```

I continue to accept ideas on how to make it cleaner.